# IP camera RTSP address

Tags: camera, video-streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I have IP camera and I don't know it's full correct url address to RTSP stream.
There is port only in RTSP settings but 192.168.1.132:554 is not enough as I understood. VLC says that rtsp stream is not found.
How can I figure out correct url address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I figure out correct url address?

1. Ask hardware vendor for documentation on this (the best solution)
2. As most cameras have a built-in web server and web client software to interact with the camera. Chances are that web client itself interacts, or at least has an option to, via RTSP. In which case you can use network sniffer, such as [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to intercept and analyze the traffic and learn the SDP locations. Checking camera settings accurately might also give some insight as for what SDP path you might need to use in RTSP requests.

There is no automatic comprehensive discovery for RTSP URLs out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont find the RTSP documentation, try to search for your camera in this listing.

[Surveillance IP Camera RTSP URLs](https://www.soleratec.com/support/rtsp/rtsp_listing)

Also, 554 is the standard port for RTSP, so normally it is not mandatory to put it in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera support ONVIF protocol, try installing ONVIF Device Manager: https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/

If the camera is detected, you will be able to see the RTSP address under the *Live Video* tab.

Check this website for screenshots: https://surveilleur.com/2019/02/25/adresse-rtsp-dune-camera-onvif/