# Create generic URL to display IP camera using openCv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-streaming, video-capture

I have an application which displays live video feed from IP Camera. I currently own two camera CP-Plus IP Camera and D-Link DCS-932l
The code i have used is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(){

CvCapture *camera=cvCaptureFromFile("http://admin:admin@172.41.20.76/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480&req_fps=30&.mjpg");
if (camera==NULL)
    printf("camera is null\n");
else
    printf("camera is not null");

cvNamedWindow("img");
while (cvWaitKey(10)!=atoi("q")){
    double t1=(double)cvGetTickCount();
    IplImage *img=cvQueryFrame(camera);
    /*if(img){
        cvSaveImage("C:/opencv.jpg",img);
    }*/
    double t2=(double)cvGetTickCount();
    printf("time: %gms  fps: %.2g\n",(t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.), 1000./((t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.)));
    cvShowImage("img",img);
}
cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

The URL works fine for the CP-Plus IP-Camera. But when I change the username,password and IP address for the d-link camera in the URL I get `NULL` for CvCapture camera; how is it possible to make generic URL. Need Help of all the experts out their.
I am using VS2010 and c++, OpenCv.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic SDP path/URL for RTSP cameras. Each particular model responds to its specific locations with or without specifiers for resolution, rate etc. Some cameras support multiple streams, with our without audio, with or without metadata and so on.

For D-Link DCS-932l, you need to either refer to its RTSP reference or otherwise documentation, or use network sniffer to detect the detail if its web client uses RTSP for transmission.

See also:

- [IP camera RTSP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285887/ip-camera-rtsp-address/18286606#18286606)

Comment: R: Thanks for taking out time and answering my question. I would like to ask you, if you have any idea about iSpy Application, then can you tell me what might be the technique used in it, that they give different kind of URL depending on the camera.

Comment: Not sure about iSpy exactly, but the approach here is pretty simple `1` you try blindly root SDP path. that is "rtsp:/host:port/" and `2` you maintain an internal database of camera models and then you look up location for specific model (per configuration) and apply it to build valid RTSP URL.

Comment: R: How can I get those all possible RTSP URL for different camera model.

Comment: `1` you collect your database, `2` you license the database from someone who has already collected it